# Intra-URL parameters and ForwardResolution mapping

Tags: java, servlets, parameters, stripes

When I've got an ActionBean with a UrlBinding like

```
@UrlBinding("/whatever/{foo}/{bar}")
```

then if in some other action I create and return a ForwardResolution to "/whatever/hello/world", I'd kind-of like it if, inside the target ActionBean, the "foo" parameter were set to "hello" and the "bar" parameter were set to "world".  As far as I can tell in Stripes 1.5.3, that does not happen.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I did think that happened, however I haven't used Stripes in a year. Could you post the two action beans?

Comment: @lucas well yes I can, but there's nothing really interesting about them at all; I've got considerable experience with Stripes so I'm pretty sure that the binding is simply not taking place. The workaround I have is to re-examine the URL (the "path info") in the getter methods to find the parameters when they're not implicitly set by the framework.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is due to Matthijs Laan on the Stripes users mailing list.  All I needed was to add a `<dispatcher>` element to the `<filter-mapping>` for Stripes in my web.xml file. Formerly it looked like this:

```
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>StripesFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>StripesDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
  </filter-mapping>
```

I just added:

```
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
```

and now it (seems to) work fine :-)